# Bar button item in a table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have a menu table view that has a bunch of cells with buttons in each of those cells. What I want to do is add a logout button at the bottom of the table view. (I would post a screenshot but don't think I have enough reputation.)

So basically, there are a couple of cells in the table view, and some blank space after it, and I would like a button at the bottom. I've tried to add a bar button item, which looks like just the thing I need on Interface Builder. However, it isn't showing up in the simulator. Is this an Autolayout issue?

What I've tried also was to add a plain Button inside the table view, but that button just sits below my last cell, and not at the bottom of the table view. If this is a feasible option, is there code to move it to the bottom right of the view?

Here's my code in the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

But nothing is showing up in the view.

Comment: This post could be a case study in how not to ask a question on SO. Hopelessly confusing, vague description of the problem, no info about the specific design or code. Come on, man! Describe what you want to do clearly and coherently. Describe what you've tried, including the *relevant* code. Explain *clearly* how what you're trying do to fails to meet your goals.

Comment: Updated. Apologies for being such a scrub on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be helpful if you gave more information, what does "it just sits in one of the cells" mean?

Do you mean you want a logout button to be on the screen only once below all of your cells?

As with most questions about IB it probably is an issue with Autolayout, so I would refer you to some examples on how to properly use buttons with tableViewCells in Autolayout...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explicit enough. Yes, I want a logout button at the bottom of the cell. So it would be an Autolayout issue?

Comment: That makes no sense. You want it at the bottom of one of your cells, or at the bottom of the whole table view?

Comment: At the bottom of the entire table view.

Comment: ok, you need to create a custom tableViewHeaderFooter. Its basically a prototype cell you can design in IB but instead of passing it as a cell, you pass it in viewForFooterInSection. Add an extra prototype cell to your tableViewController in IB, set its class to a custom class, put your logout button in it with autolayout and pass the cell as the footerView for the section :)

Comment: remember to check my answer if this helped you out! thanks